# How to modify Pytest status while maintaining original behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to include the hook `pytest_report_teststatus` in `conftest.py`.

However, simply including this hook seems to modify the behavior of the `TerminalReporter` such that it then prints the status of each test 3x (instead of 1x) which I'm assuming is the `setup`, `call`, and `teardown`. This happens even if the hook itself is not modified.

Would really appreciate any insight on why this is happening and how to overcome it.

Using the following `conftest.py`

```
# Original, unmodified hook

def pytest_report_teststatus(report):
    if report.passed:
        letter = "."
    elif report.skipped:
        letter = "s"
    elif report.failed:
        letter = "F"
        if report.when != "call":
            letter = "f"
    return report.outcome, letter, report.outcome.upper()
```

Results in each test being written to the terminal 3 times

```
test_foo.py::test_output_1 PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
test_foo.py::test_output_1 PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                          
test_foo.py::test_output_1 PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
test_foo.py::test_output_2 PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
test_foo.py::test_output_2 PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
test_foo.py::test_output_2 PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                                
test_foo.py::test_output_3 PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
test_foo.py::test_output_3 PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                         
test_foo.py::test_output_3 PASSED
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()

    if report.when == "call":
        if report.passed and report.duration < 0.01:
            report.outcome = 'failed' # Here will change report from PASSED to FAILED
            status_id = 4  # retest
        elif report.passed:
            status_id = 1  # passed
        elif report.failed:
            status_id = 5  # failed
        test_rail(report, item, status_id)
```